# TryGetObjectByKey() doesn't return entity with Added state (EF 6)

Tags: entity-framework

**1. Q #1**

I have POCO

```
    public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }       
}
```

In my DbContext I have func

```
 public void AttachUpdated<T>( T objectDetached) where T : class
    {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, objectDetached);

        object original;
        if (objContext.TryGetObjectByKey(entityKey, out original))
            objContext.ApplyCurrentValues(entityKey.EntitySetName, objectDetached);
        else
            objContext.AddObject(entityKey.EntitySetName, objectDetached);}
```

So i want to add some Products to context

var p1 = new Product(){Id =  "1", Name = "Product 1";}
var p2 = new Product(){Id =  "1", Name = "Product 1";}

ctx.AttachUpdated(p1);

And when i try to add identical Product (with same Id as first product) TryGetObjectByKey() doesn't find already added product.
ctx.AttachUpdated(p2);

Therefore I need to use ctx.SaveChanges() or AccseptAllChanges() and then 
ctx.AttachUpdated(p2) work as expected. 
I can't understand where i have problem in my code.

1. Q #2

   var p1 = new Product() { Id = "1", Name = "Product 1" };

   ```
           var v1 = new Version() { Number = "1.0", Type = "Release", ReleaseDate = "01/01/13" };

           p1.Versions = new List<Version>();

           p1.Versions.Add(v1);

           ctx.AttachUpdated(p1);
   ```

And then i see that v1 was addet to DbSet(). But why? And how i could prevent such bihavior. I need to add only Product and not related Versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void AttachOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);

        var original = this.context.Set<T>().Find(entityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value);

        if (original != null)
        {
            this.context.Entry<T>(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);                
        }
        else
            objContext.AddObject(entityKey.EntitySetName, entity);
    }
```